# subscriber is not working properly using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

In my footer i have a subscriber form in which any user can subscribe to website.

**Form is**

```
<form id="newsletter-signup" action="?action=signup" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
    <input type="submit" id="signup-button" value="" />
</form>
```

I want to use ajax for submitting data in the database. i have never used ajax before so there is a problem in it and i cant solve it.I have used action action="?action=signup" due to which whenever i clicked on this it goes to 404.html. All the other tasks are working fine . Email is stored in database and all other checks are also working fine. I want this that it does not go to 404.html page . instead of this it should display this message that subscribed successfully.Script portion is this.

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#newsletter-signup').submit(function() {
            //check the form is not currently submitting
            if ($(this).data('formstatus') !== 'submitting') {
                //setup variables
                var form = $(this),
                    formData = form.serialize(),
                    formUrl = form.attr('action'),
                    formMethod = form.attr('method'),
                    responseMsg = $('#signup-response');
                //add status data to form
                form.data('formstatus', 'submitting');
                //send data to server for validation
                $.ajax({
                        url: formUrl,
                        type: formMethod,
                        data: formData,
                        success: function(data) {
                            //setup variables
                            var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data),
                                klass = '';
                            //response conditional
                            switch (responseData.status) {
                                case 'error':
                                    klass = 'response-error';
                                    break;
                                case 'success':
                                    klass = 'response-success';
                                    break;
                            }
                        });
                }
            });
    }
    //prevent form from submitting
    return false;
});
```

**Data is stored in database as this**

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'signup'){
    //Data storing code     
}
```

all these files are in footer.php.

Comment: Two things -- `(1)` if you remove `action="?action=signup" ` from the form and add this as `form url ` from javascript part and `(2)` show the success message from the `ajax success` function - this code should work.

Comment: action="?action=signup" if i remove this then data is not stored in the database.@Himel Nag Rana

Comment: after removing it from Form - you need to add the same to `formUrl` value. Did adding it to `formUrl` value - resulted in not storing data?

Comment: See @Rohit's answer as follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have some syntax error after success function.

I updated the code like this after document ready

```js
$('#newsletter-signup').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
            //check the form is not currently submitting
            if ($(this).data('formstatus') !== 'submitting') {
                //setup variables
                var form = $(this),
                    formData = form.serialize(),
                    formUrl = form.attr('action'),
                    formMethod = form.attr('method'),
                    responseMsg = $('#signup-response');
                //add status data to form
                form.data('formstatus', 'submitting');
                //send data to server for validation
                $.ajax({
                        url: formUrl,
                        type: formMethod,
                        data: formData,
                        success: function(data) {alert(data);
                            //setup variables
                            var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data),
                                klass = '';
                            //response conditional
                            switch (responseData.status) {
                                case 'error':
                                    klass = 'response-error';
                                    break;
                                case 'success':
                                    klass = 'response-success';
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                })
            }
    });
```

Try to use some debugging tools like firebug. Please try to update the code and check.

Comment: where is the logic here that it will not move to next page or load the same page

Comment: e.preventDefault() will prevent executing the default action of the submit button.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

**Correction in your Html Form Code :**

```
<form id="newsletter-signup" action="#123" method="post">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
    <input type="submit" id="signup-button" value="" />
</form>
```

Don't use `?action=signup` give proper page path i.e.`page.php?action=signup` or use ajax call to save the form data and show the successful message on same page.

**Correction in your Script code :**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#newsletter-signup').submit(function() {
    console.log("rohit");
    return false;
            //check the form is not currently submitting
            if ($(this).data('formstatus') !== 'submitting') {
                //setup variables
                var form = $(this),
                    formData = form.serialize(),
                    formUrl = 'page.php?action=signup',
                    formMethod = form.attr('method'),
                    responseMsg = $('#signup-response');
                //add status data to form
                form.data('formstatus', 'submitting');
                //send data to server for validation
                $.ajax({
                        url: formUrl,
                        type: formMethod,
                        data: formData,
                        success: function(data) {
                            //setup variables
                            var responseData = jQuery.parseJSON(data),
                                class = '';
                            //response conditional
                            switch (responseData.status) {
                                case 'error':
                                    class = 'response-error';
                                    break;
                                case 'success':
                                    class = 'response-success';
                                    break;
                            }
                            }
                        });
                }
    });
    //prevent form from submitting
    return false;
});
```

**page.php :**

```
if($_GET['action'] == 'signup'){
    // Your code comes here.    
}
```

Comment: it is in the footer . page.php should also me some page?

Comment: @R J . footer is included in every page of the website

Comment: `page.php` is the page from where you send the form information into the database using AJAX call and on suceesfully save you return a promise on same page where you write the ajax code.

Comment: I updated my answer with `page.php` file code. I hope you need the same.It will surely work. try it

Comment: @Waqas_aamer, you checked ?

Comment: @R J thanks alot. I have used on click event . i have replaced the whole code with new code.

Comment: @R J . i will apply this also to check it.